# PCB Routing / Pipe Routing Problem / nPairs of disjoint shortest-paths in Python 3.x with NetworkX Package

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, shortest-path

I am looking for a efficient solution for solving a multiple shortest-path problem in `Python3.7` with the `NetworkX` package. For one pair `(source_node, target_node)` in a given `nx.Graph()`,the solution would be an A* path generated by `nx.astar_path(G, source, target)`.

Now i want to find the shortest-path (weighted edges) for `n` **pairs of source/target node**. The additional constraint is, that the **paths can't cross**, like a set of pipes or routes on a PCB. So each Node is limited to be used once.

My solution would be to run A-stars on all pairs of nodes and remove them after each run from the graph. Doing this for all permutations of my set of source/sinks. But i guess this is extremly inefficient and i am missing out on a lot of optimal solutions. Can you guys name a better approach than this?

Here the package documentation: networkx.github.io/documentation/stable

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Networkx has changed a lot since version 1.10.  Here is more up to date documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/  (now version 2.4)

Comment: Can you specify the problem more in detail? Is the pair of source/target pair pre-defined or do you have n source/target nodes and you need to pair them up in an optimal way? Is it guaranteed that a valid connection between each source and target exists? Do the assumptions for A* hold or is additional info (e.g. nodes are 3D coordinates) given?